# Apache Settings to Secure Files

Tags: apache

In the past I have used two methods for securing files for web apps.

1. Put them outside of webroot (which is usually {www || http}/app). So files would usually be stored outside apache altogether.

OR

2. Restrict access within my .htaccess file

My friend suggested another alternative which is similar to option 1 but allows all files to remain together. He suggested that when setting up my virtual host I adjust the path to {www || http}/app/public.

This option would allow me to store all related files in {www || http}/app and just store all private files in {www || http}/app/private

Should there be any concerns with this method?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you. Isn't this basically suggesting that you use a different webroot for the virtual host (i.e. `.../app/public` instead of `.../app`) and then having the private files outside the webroot - i.e. exactly the same as option 1, only with a different webroot?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It should be self explanatory but I have been caught with "gotchas" before and always like to confirm new information.

Comment: I understand. In this case - this is exactly the same as option 1 only with a different webroot and thus it provides the same security.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from @SteffenUllrich

> This is exactly the same as option 1 only with a different webroot and
> thus it provides the same security.